# Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object

Tags: javascript, dom

tengo un problema al hacer un appendChild al input con el resultado de una operacion que toma 2 inputs.

```
<input id="firstNumber" type="text" value="" /> + <input id="secondNumber" type="text" value="" /> = <input id="resultNumber" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateSumListener();" />
```

para esto tengo la siguiente funcion.

```
function calculateSumListener() {
//Return the value of the input #firstNumber
var stringA = document.getElementById('firstNumber').value; 
//Return the value of the input #secondNumber
var stringB = document.getElementById('secondNumber').value; 

//your code goes here
let result = document.getElementById('resultNumber');

// reasignar
let value = parseInt(stringA) + parseInt(stringB);
result.appendChild(value); }
```

El error que presenta en ***Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `appendChild` permite "insertar" un elemento `HTML` dentro de otro, es decir que el argumento que le tienes que dar debe ser un `HTMLElement`, en tu ejemplo el argumento es de tipo `number`.

En su lugar usa:

```
result.value = value;
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: eres un genio! gracias!!! solucionado